# Cannot reselect item on select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have problem with all version select2. I use bootstrap, and I have my select2 in modal.

When I want to reselect something, so I have chosen  a option, and after that I changed it, I got a error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
    at HTMLLIElement.<anonymous> (select2.full.min.js:1:7322)
    at Function.each (jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:2:2882)
    at n.fn.init.each (jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:2:847)
    at select2.full.min.js:1:7263
    at d.current (select2.full.min.js:1:30340)
    at c.setClasses (select2.full.min.js:1:7129)
    at e.<anonymous> (select2.full.min.js:1:9234)
    at d.invoke (select2.full.min.js:1:4866)
    at d.trigger (select2.full.min.js:1:4685)
    at e.trigger (select2.full.min.js:2:26037)
```

Here:

```
c.prototype.setClasses = function () {
    var b = this;
    this.data.current(function (c) {
        var d = a.map(c, function (a) {
            return a.id.toString()
        })
            , e = b.$results.find(".select2-results__option[aria-selected]");
        e.each(function () {
            var b = a(this)
                , c = a.data(this, "data")
                , e = "" + c.id;
            null != c.element && c.element.selected || null == c.element && a.inArray(e, d) > -1 ? b.attr("aria-selected", "true") : b.attr("aria-selected", "false")
        });
        var f = e.filter("[aria-selected=true]");
        f.length > 0 ? f.first().trigger("mouseenter") : e.first().trigger("mouseenter")
    })
}
```

It does the same outside the boostrap model.

Anyone know something?

Comment: The error means that either `a` of `c` in your code is undefined. My guess would be `c` as you hide the outer context by redefining it inside the `current()` function. Given the lack of detail in the code sample, we can't provide any further information.

Comment: I understand the problem, but I don't know what's wrong if I use orginal select2 plugin. When I load data by ajax, everything works. When I try to add plugin to existing html select, I got this error.

Comment: It is possible you are using the wrong jQuery version with select2. Try the non-minified code to debug if you can.

Comment: "*add to existing html `select`*" - can you provide that html select and how you setup select2?  Ideally in a stack snippet - the [SO wiki for select2](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-select2/info) has a "starter kit" - make you you change it to the match the versions that you're using.

Comment: TinyMCE JQuery plugin affected my select2. After remove it everything works.